# Use one table for different resource in Laravel Nova

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-nova

I'm trying to create something like a blogging system inside the Laravel Nova.

I have a table named `articles` as well as abstract model `AbstractArctile`.
I also have 3 categories:

- **News -** `App\Models\News\Article` extending the `App\Models\Abstract\AbstractArticle`
- **Digests -** `App\Models\Digests\Article` extending the `App\Models\Abstract\AbstractArticle`
- **Offtopic -** `App\Models\Offtopic\Article` extending the `App\Models\Abstract\AbstractArticle`

The table `articles` has a field named **category**, and there are 3 types of categories: *news, digests, offtopic*.

Besides the extending the abstract model, each *resource* model also has one attribute defined, which is it's **category** in the following manner:

```
/**
 * To which category this article belongs to
 * @var array
 */
protected $attributes = [
    'category'  =>  'news'
];
```

I have no problem creating the articles under the specified categories in the Nova, however, instead of showing the articles from specified category, it displays articles from all categories on all resources.

Is there a way to display articles only from certain category on a given resource?

### Summary

One abstract model -> 3 resources extending that model (with category attribute defined) -> how to display only items from that category inside the nova resource?

Comment: IIRC, you can override the `indexQuery` function in each resource.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can make use of Laravel eloquent [query scope](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent#query-scopes).

Add global scope like below to all 3 models (`App\Models\News\Article`, `App\Models\Digests\Article`, `App\Models\Offtopic\Article`),  which is a easy way to make sure every query for a given model receives category constrains.

```
protected static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    static::addGlobalScope('category', function (Builder $builder) {
        $builder->where('category', 'news'); // Change the value depends on the model
    });
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Perfect solution! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

In Nova, you can use indexQuery,detailQuery and editQuery as well and customize your resource results.

https://nova.laravel.com/docs/4.0/resources/authorization.html#index-filtering